# how to find out Fully qualified name IntelliJ project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, fully-qualified-naming

I have an IntelliJ project with 2 scala objects, as below:

```
cloudera@quickstart tlf]$ ll
total 8
-rwxrw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 1601 May  2 15:45 AnalyzeGraphTlf.scala
-rwxrw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 1868 May  2 13:35 FormatDataTlf.scala
[cloudera@quickstart tlf]$ ls
AnalyzeGraphTlf.scala  FormatDataTlf.scala
[cloudera@quickstart tlf]$ pwd
/home/cloudera/ideaProjects/grafoTelefonos/src/main/scala/tlf
```

How can I know the fully qualified name of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to convention that IDEA follows (and maven, and most Java & Scala developers do) all Scala sources goes to 
${projectDir}/src/main/scala

Java sources to:
${projectDir}/src/main/java

And so on...

in case Your Scala sources goes to:
home/cloudera/ideaProjects/grafoTelefonos/src/main/scala

Full qualified name of the package begins after '/scala' . In your case it is 'tlf'
And in addition fully qualified name of class AnalyzeGraphTlf.scala is 'tlf.AnalyzeGraphTlf'

Note that Full qualified name reflects directory structure and use  '.' (dot) as a separator.